# check access toke is valid with github action

Tags: github, github-actions, renovate

In Github I have created a personal access token in https://github.com/settings/tokens

Than added it to https://github.com/myrepo/settings/secrets/actions Repository secrets

with full repo rights

[image]

I tried to run a renovate bot action

```
jobs:
renovate:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Show Repo
        env:
        GH_REPO: ${{ github.repository }}
        run: echo "run on $GH_REPO"
    - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3.5.3
    - name: Self-hosted Renovate
        env:
        REPO_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.RENOVATE_TOKEN  }}
        uses: renovatebot/github-action@v39.0.1
        with:
        token: "$REPO_TOKEN"
```

which fails with

```
"Authentication failure"
```

I tried to check with curl

```
curl -v -H 'Authorization: token <my token>' 'https://github.com/<my-repo>'
```

but didn't get any insights

Is there a way to actually use that secret in an action (or with curl) to check if it has valid acces for repository maintenance ?

Comment: Can you share your workflow yml file?

Comment: Have added an answer. Does it work for you?

Comment: it did complain in the same way. Would you know a simple action to check if the token has enough rights to do a repo read , repo add issue?

Comment: Can you share what are the permissions now available for the token?

Comment: @Robin Thomas the token has everything below repo

Comment: Did you create `Personal access tokens (classic)` or finely grained token?

Comment: personal access token (classic)

Comment: Is this how your permission look like: https://i.imgur.com/9JmSzwo.png
You need to have `repo` selected as well (not just the ones below)

Comment: yes that's what I menat with everything below repo. Added also a picture for clarification to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Update:

Since you are using self-hosted renovate bot, you need to set the two envs as well:

```
RENOVATE_AUTODISCOVER: true
RENOVATE_AUTODISCOVER_FILTER: "renovate-try/*"
```

> When you enable autodiscover, by default, Renovate runs on every repository that the bot account can access. You can limit which repositories Renovate can access by using the autodiscoverFilter config option.
>
> https://docs.renovatebot.com/self-hosted-configuration/#autodiscover

---

Have fixed your workflow file:

```
jobs:
  renovate:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Show Repo
        run: echo "run on ${{ github.repository }}"
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3.5.3
      - name: Self-hosted Renovate
        uses: renovatebot/github-action@v39.0.1
        with:
          token: ${{ secrets.RENOVATE_TOKEN }}
```

---

1. I have simplified your workflow yaml file.
2. Removed the need for `env.REPO_TOKEN`  since you can directly access the `secrets.RENOVATE_TOKEN`. The same for `GH_REPO`.
3. Fixed your workflow formatting as well.

---

Another issue might be that your `secrets.RENOVATE_TOKEN` do not have the necessary permission to do this action.

You need to create a `Personal access tokens (classic)` here: https://github.com/settings/tokens

You'll need atleast `repo:public_repo` scope for public repos, and `repo` scope for private repos.

Comment: that's what I did. It has actually all repo rights.. Can you change your example to check these rights ?

Comment: Thanks and extra kudos for your extended help in the Chat !